# RecyclerView LinearLayout always appearing on top of other elements

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

I have this screen called `Messages` that displays a list of recent messages to the user. In my `activity_messages.xml` file I have this bit of code:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_line"
    android:layout_width="351dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.47"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/Game_Button"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.216" />
```

Basically, this block of code creates a horizontal line. Below that horizontal, I want to display the user's recent messages.

Below that horizontal line block of code, I have this code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="64dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="168dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

This takes care of displaying the user's recent messages.

Now in my `Messages.java` file I have this bit of code:

```
mMessagesLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Messages.this);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mMessagesLayoutManager);
mMessagesAdapter = new MessagesAdapter(getDataSetMessages(), Messages.this);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMessagesAdapter);

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    MessagesObject obj = new MessagesObject(Integer.toString(i));
    resultsMessages.add(obj);
}
mMessagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This code is for testing purposes, but it works. It shows all the user's messages a linear order and I am able to scroll through them. My only problem is when I run the program, the recent messages don't start below the horizontal line. Some of the messages are above the horizontal line and on top of the other elements. I think the first message jumps to position (0,0).

How do I fix this? I would like my messages to appear the way they are right now, just below the horizontal line.

Comment: post your full  activity_messages.xml file code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

> ```
> <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="64dp"
>     tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="168dp">
> ```

to this instead:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/horizontal_line"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
```

Two major changes going on here:

- `ConstraintLayout` doesn't fully support `match_parent`, so we use `0dp` (which means "match constraints") instead.
- Add constraints for all four sides. The start/end constraints make the view fill the screen horizontally, and the top/bottom constraints make the view fill everything from below the line to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks for the clarification for using `match_parent` inside `ConstraintLayout`. Didn't know about that.

Answer (score 1):

it is just Constrain issue.
You haven't set constraint for recyclerview try to add constrain and run again
it will work

Answer (score 1):

You can either wrap both views the first view and the scrollview in a LinearLayout with android:orientation="vertical", or you can add constraints (if the root view is a ConstraintLayout)